# Applescript repeat command for each item in list. Each line added to command as variable

Tags: variables, applescript, repeat

I have a list of movie titles stored in a variable `movie_titles` in AppleScript.

```
{"Beautiful Girl 2014
The Aerialist 2020
Yvonne Orji Momma I Made It 2020
Dead Stop 2011
"}
```

I need to run a command for each title in that list. Open a URL where each title of the list `movie_titles` is a part of that url. The result being a tab for each item in the list opened in my default browser.

```
repeat with i in movie_titles
    do shell script "open 'http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q= " & movie_titles & "&s=tt&ttype=ft'"
    
end repeat
```

That works for a list of one but it adds each line of a list of more than one into the URL. I realize that I need a second variable that grabs each line in succession and adds it to each repeat but I am not sure how to add this to the repeat statement.

I think I couldn't find a good example because I am not sure which search words/phrase to use. If you can provide an answer and a short explanation I would appreciate.

Comment: There isn't any concatenation, your "list" is just a single string item - how are you trying to get the items (dialog, file, etc)?

Comment: Ok. I used the incorrect term. I  need to use each item in that list in the repeat loop individually. As it stands it's not doing that.

Comment: Your list only has one item (the string) -  how you are getting the text?

Comment: Strings are separated by commas. These values are not separated by commas, this is a list.

Comment: Yes, your **single** string is in a list.  Are you wanting to break up some  input string, or are the individual items supposed to already be a list?

Comment: I want each line to be a list item. For AppleScript is it supposed to look like this:{"Beautiful Girl 2014", "The Aerialist 2020", "Yvonne Orji Momma I Made It 2020", "Dead Stop 2011"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break up the input string at the line endings in order to create the list items.  AppleScript text objects have a `paragraphs` element that uses return, linefeed, or return/linefeed as delimiters, so you can do something like:

```
set movieTitles to "Beautiful Girl 2014
The Aerialist 2020
Yvonne Orji Momma I Made It 2020
Dead Stop 2011"

repeat with anItem in paragraphs of movieTitles
   if contents of anItem is not "" then -- skip blank lines
       do shell script "open 'http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" & anItem & "&s=tt&ttype=ft'"
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I had to remove `as list` from the end of my first line where I save the clipboard items to a variable in order for `paragraphs` to work.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, that was why I was asking where you were getting the text from.  You were just coercing the entire clipboard string to a single list item.

Comment: @John It would be better to use `open location`—which is a builtin AppleScript function—rather than `do shell script`, which ends up being a really roundabout series of operations that ultimately ends up sending the exact same `GURL` Apple Event that `open location` does.  You can replace the `do shell script` line with the simpler **`open location "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&ttype=ft&q=" & anItem`**.

Comment: @red_menace Another question if you would. If I wanted to repeat through that same list and separate the title and date for each line how would I do that. I need to assign the year and date to separate variables.  
`repeat with y in paragraphs of movie_titles`   
`set movie_title to text 1 through -6 of y`   
`set movie_year to text -4 thru -1 of y`   
`end repeat`   
I am only getting the last line of the list here  {"Dead Stop", "2015"}

Comment: @John That works, you would just need to concatenate the strings and variables in the desired order for the shell script.  Your result seems to indicate you are creating another list.